# Issues in json.stringify in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here in the javascript code, when I invoke that function, this alert will print JSON, but it is missing some values. Totally there are 3 fields (group of 2), sometimes they will print like this:

```
{"":"01bce391-d3a2-4582-8e53-6a45bb583284","cast":"07392eb1-c356-4760-8f4c-  
62ff164ca721"}
```

or

```
{"":"01bce391-d3a2-4582-8e53-6a45bb583284","asd":"01bce391-
d3a2-4582-8e53-6a45345242","cast":"07392eb1-c356-4760-8f4c-62ff164ca721"}
```

The counter:

```
var counteradd=4;
$("#getButton").click(function () {
    var jsonadd = {};
    for(i=1; i<counteradd;i++) {
        jsonadd[$('#textboxadd' + i).val()] = $('#searchaddid' + i).val();
        alert('#searchaddid' + i);
        alert($('#searchaddid' + i).val());
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonadd));
});
```

Comment: What is this?? `var = counteradd=4;` it is like `var counteradd = 4`

Comment: It's a syntax error.  I'm not sure how that happened.  John - please post your code to http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I'm thinking the selector $("#textboxadd" + i).val() is incorrect. You could trace it out...

Comment: Can you give us the rest of the code?  html etc?  Make a www.jsfiddle.net of it even?

Comment: here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amjhn/Cz5Yf/4/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but there were a few bugs I needed to fix in order to get this to work:

- Add an extra bracket and parentheses to the end of the code.
- Change `newTextBoxDivcast.after().html(` to `newTextBoxDivcast.append(`. The `$.after()` function will create a new element as a sibling to that object and then forget about it. Then the `$.html()` will replace the HTML of that current object with what you insert.
- Change the line where the jsoncastadd object gets defined so that its value comes from `$('#secastadd' + i)`. In your code here, `$('#searchcastaddid' + i)` is always empty and never touched.
- Add jQuery as an external resource to the fiddle you provided.

One reason you might have problems is if the same key is used more than once. For example, `jsoncastadd["blah"] = 5` and `jsoncastadd["blah"] = 6` will leave you with just `{"blah":"6"}` in the end.

Here's the resulting code I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countercastadd=1;
    $(document).on('click', '.removebtnaddcast', function() {
        var finalremadd = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/);
        alert(finalremadd);
        $('#searchcastaddid'+ finalremadd).attr('value','');
        $('#textboxcastadd'+ finalremadd).val("");
        $('#secastadd'+ finalremadd).val("");
    });
    $("#addc").click(function () {
        var newTextBoxDivcast = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", 'TextBoxDivcast' + countercastadd);
        newTextBoxDivcast.append(' <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="searchcastadd' + countercastadd +
            '" id="secastadd' + countercastadd + '" value=""> <input type="text" placeholder="Cast" name="Castadd' + countercastadd +
            '" id="textboxcastadd' + countercastadd + '" value="" > <input type="button" id="removebtnaddcast' + countercastadd +
            '" class="removebtnaddcast" value="-" > <input type="hidden"  name="searchcastaddid' + countercastadd +
            '" id="searchcastaddid' + countercastadd + '" value="" >');
        newTextBoxDivcast.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup1");
        countercastadd++;
        //alert(countercastadd);
    });
    $("#getButton").click(function () {
        var jsoncastadd = {};
        for(i=1; i<countercastadd;i++)
            jsoncastadd[$('#textboxcastadd' + i).val()] = $('#secastadd' + i).val();
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsoncastadd));
    });
});
```